# Synology - How to delete versioning DB

Tags: versioning, synology

I cannot find how to delete the versioning database. I disabled versioning on all my folders:

[image]

In the drive admin console I still get 2.5 TB used for versioning:

[image]

but there is no data in the version explorer:

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It was well hidden, but I found it ! https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Collaboration/How_to_manage_storage_in_Drive#Uninstall:

*Historical versions are saved in Synology Drive Server database. You can uninstall the package to free up space. Please note that once the database is deleted, there is no way to restore the historical versions. Therefore, please make sure those information on Synology Drive Server is no longer needed before uninstalling the package.
Go to Package Center > Synology Drive Server > Uninstall, and tick Delete the items listed above when uninstalling the package.*